# Error when drawing a d3.js line with no data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js line chart, with multiple lines. Users can change filters associated with each line, which changes the values plotted, and the chart updates.

This all works fine, but if the user chooses filters which result in no matching values for a line, I get this error in the console:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d=""          d3.js:8481
attrNull                                                d3.js:8481
(anonymous function)                                    d3.js:8653
d3_class.forEach                                        d3.js:275
start                                                   d3.js:8652
(anonymous function)                                    d3.js:8646
d3_timer_mark                                           d3.js:2085
d3_timer_step                                           d3.js:2065
```

What's visible to the user is fine - the line (obviously) doesn't draw when the chart updates. But I'd like to get rid of the error! Here's the code which enters/updates/removes the lines:

```
var line = g.selectAll('path.line')
            .data(function(d) { return d; },
                  function(d) { return d.id; });

line.enter().append('path')
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('id', function(d) { return lineCSSID(d.id); })
      .style('stroke', function(d) { return d.color; });

line.data(function(d) { return d; })
    .transition()
    .attr('d', function(d) { return chartLine(d.values); });

line.exit().remove();
```

The error occurs when the `return chartLine(d.values);` is called and `d.values` is an empty array. Is there something I can do which will let it fail more gracefully?

In case it affects the answer: the user can then change that line's filters again and, if that results in there being matching data, the line will be redrawn.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I should actually process the data before I pass it into the chart, and not pass in any line that has no point values? I'm not sure whether that or a fix in the chart code would be more d3-like...

Comment: Yes, I think the best way to handle this would be to filter the data which has no values instead of passing it in. Alternatively, you could put in some dummy `d` value.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I'm not sure what you mean by a dummy `d` value?

Comment: A non-empty string that doesn't draw anything visible, e.g. a dot outside the shown area. This would be just to get rid of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up by omitting any lines with no data before I add the data to the chart.

For example, if (somewhere before the code in my question) I had something like this, where `data` is an array of objects, each one representing a single line on the chart:

```
var svg = d3.select('.chart')
              .selectAll('svg')
                .data([data]);
```

Then before that I now do this:

```
data = data.filter(function(d){ return d.values.length > 0; });
```

This ensures that any lines with no datapoints aren't passed to the chart.

**UPDATE:** I realised that if *all* the line(s) have filters that result in no matching values, then I get errors when trying to calculate the `domain` for the x axis. So I've now got something like this:

```
if (data.length == 0) {
  // We must have filtered out all the lines because none had any values.
  // Fake an x-axis domain between 1 year ago and today.
  var to = new Date(),
      from = new Date(),
  from.setFullYear(from.getFullYear() - 1);
  xScale.domain([from, to]);

} else {
  // Standard, set the x-axis domain as usual from min/max values of all lines.
  ... 
};

xScale.range([0, width]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some conditionality so that you only return if d.values isn't an empty array?

```
if(d.values.length > 0){
    return chartLine(d.values);
}
```

Comment: But there is no `d` in scope in the first line of your second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the game but consider using [d3.line](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line) and declaring where the data is define with [line.defined](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line_defined).  This is a d3 built-in method to accommodating missing data.

for example:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d[hasData]; })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```

Where `function(d) { return d[hasData]; }` should return a truthy value if the object contains data, else return false.  If false is returned, d3 will skip rendering that particular data element.

If your data was:

```
var data = [{name:"foo", value:1, hasData:true}, {name:"bar", value:0, hasData:false}]
```

The above setup of `d3.line` will skip the second object (`"bar"`).  Also, because `0` is falsy and any positive `int` or `float` is truthy, you can simply use `function(d) { return d.value; }`.

Mike himself made an example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0533f44f2cfabecc5e3a).

Cheers.